# How to Upload File to Sharepoint Via Commandline?

Tags: 2010, file-upload, webdav

Salvete!  How can I, from the commandline, upload a file to a document library?
Now, I found [davcopy](http://www.bluedoglimited.com/Downloads/SitePages/DavCopy.aspx), which works, sort of.  I can only upload the file using my domain account that I am already logged in with.  If I give credentials (even my own!) the fail.

But I am not attached to davcopy.  Maybe there is another way to do this from the commandline?  I do want to avoid powershell, because I need to provide a way for this to be done to certain users who don't have powershell.

I am thinking it could be done using some sort of dav service.

Comment: It is not working for me at all...
Can anybody help.... Showing message in cmd : Syntax is not correct

Comment: Well, what is your commandline?

Comment: I think he was missing /user:

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Believe it or not, you can use Windows `net use` to map a sharepoint library to a drive letter! Then you can use plain old `copy` or `xcopy` or whatever.

```
net use r: https://some.portal.org/documents [password] user:domainName\[username]
copy c:\somefile.txt r:\somefile.txt
```

[Here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MappingConnectingADriveLetterToAWebDAVOrFrontPageWebsite.aspx) is where I found that answer.  I've done this, and it works like a charm.  You can even specify whatever credentials you like, too.

Comment: This is also the equivalent of using Windows Explorer and Map Network Drive R:\.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but the ideas was to do this from the commandline.

Comment: Yep just in case :)

Comment: I don't think this works with Sharepoint Online now.

Answer (score 1):

you can also just call the DavWWWRoot as well.

so your url to your library is something like
`http://sharepoint/Site/SubSite/Library`

your copy command would be 
`copy somefile.txt \\sharepoint\DavWWWRoot\Site\SubSite\Library`

Should work like a charm.

Edit.  You will have to have at least one active File Explorer Connection to somewhere for this to work.

Comment: Welcome to the StackExchange community! This sounds like a good answer, do you know of any documentation to support it? I could see that being very useful to other people who come across this question.

Comment: I tried just what you did, and got the response `The system cannot find the path specified`.  Maybe this only works on the server?  How can my computer know that \\sharepoint is a web address and NOT a network computer?

Comment: I tried it on the server and the response was `1 file(s) copied` - so something happened!  But I can't find the file anywhere....  I don't know what it did do.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [Sync FileSystem and SharePoint List](http://listsync.codeplex.com/) on codeplex

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I had in mind.

Comment: @ashis-patel please add a good summary of your answer and *then* link. "link only answers" is of less use for our site, since links tend to die.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Case in point: `Shutting down CodePlex - Brian Harry's Blog`

Answer (score 0):

REM For example the following Batch file copies files to SharePoint.
REM Create a drive letter that maps to a SharePoint destination folder with NET USE.
NET USE http://sharepoint
REM Change to the source folder
C:
CD \SourceFolder
REM Copy the files
REM where C:\SourceFolder is the source folder
REM and S:\destinationFolder is destination on SharePoint.
COPY SourceFiles.* "S:\destinationFolder"